# Как обработать SqlException - The parametrised query ... expects the parameter ... which is not supplied

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Имеется форма, на которой расположен DataGridView и к ней BindingNavigator, созданный автоматически.

[image: Форма]

Во время работы, нажимаю удалить, тем самым удаляя строчку. А потом жму сохранить и получаю ошибку.

[image: Ошибка]

```
        private void WhBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.whBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.mainDBDataSet); // ругается на эту строчку
    }
```

Поломав голову, поспрашивая у гугла, ответа не нашёл. Буду признателен помощи. Предоставлю всю необходимую дополнительную информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась.
Источники данных => Правой кнопкой мыши по таблице/бд => Изменить набор данных в конструкторе => Правой кнопкой мыши по адаптеру => Настроить => Дополнительно
Поставить галочку в "Обновить таблицу данных".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так удалил стандартную кнопку удаления строки и заменил на новую.
Код кнопки:

```
    shopBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    shopBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.Validate();
    this.shopBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.shopTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(this.mainDBDataSet);
```

shop замените на названия ваших адаптеров и тд.

Попытался описать максимально подробно. Вдруг кому-то пригодится